# Guava EventBus throwing handlerExcetion when different instances of the same class are registered on the bus

Tags: java, swing, event-handling, guava

I am having difficulty registering multiple instances of the same class onto one Google guava event bus. If a single instance of a class is registered, it runs fine, if I try to register more then one instance, it throws a handlerException.
Full error:

```
Feb 24, 2015 10:37:25 PM com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus$LoggingSubscriberExceptionHandler handleException

SEVERE: Could not dispatch event: backend.modules.SingleSeriesLineChartModule[,2,25,834x485,layout=java.awt.FlowLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=9,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=] to public void backend.modules.SingleSeriesLineChartModule.serialDataEventHandler(backend.serial.SerialDataEvent)
```

Here is how I am registering the listeners:

```
        module1 = new SingleSeriesLineChartModule("Test Graph1", moduleContainer, tabbedPane1, "AA", "Var");
        serialCommunicator.serialRegister(module1);
        module2 = new SingleSeriesLineChartModule("Test Graph1", moduleContainer, tabbedPane2, "AA", "Var");
        serialCommunicator.serialRegister(module2);
        module3 = new SingleSeriesLineChartModule("Test Graph3", moduleContainer, tabbedPane3, "AA", "Var");
        serialCommunicator.serialRegister(module3);
        module4 = new SingleSeriesLineChartModule("Test Graph4", moduleContainer, tabbedPane4, "AA", "Var");
        serialCommunicator.serialRegister(module4);
```

The registering code in the SerialCommunicator class:

```
    public void serialRegister(Object registree){
        serialEventBus.register(registree);
    }

    public void serialUnregister(Object unregistree){
        serialEventBus.unregister(unregistree);
    }
```

The serialEventBus is just an unedited guava eventBus

The SingleSeriesLineChartModule (A long name I know, I'm working on it):

```
public class SingleSeriesLineChartModule extends AbstractModule{

    private final String SERIAL_KEY;
    private final String Y_AXIS_LABEL;
    private static XYSeries series;

    public SingleSeriesLineChartModule(String title, ModuleContainer container, JTabbedPane tabbedPane, String serialKey, String yAxisLabel) {
        super(title, container, tabbedPane);
        SERIAL_KEY = serialKey;
        Y_AXIS_LABEL = yAxisLabel;

        series = new XYSeries(SERIAL_KEY, false, false);

        JFreeChart chart = createChart(new XYSeriesCollection(series));
        ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
        this.add(chartPanel);

    }

    private JFreeChart createChart(XYDataset data){
        JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart(TITLE, "Time(s)", Y_AXIS_LABEL, data);
        XYPlot plot = (XYPlot)chart.getPlot();
        plot.setRangePannable(true);
        plot.setDomainPannable(true);
        NumberAxis numberAxis = (NumberAxis)plot.getRangeAxis();
        numberAxis.setStandardTickUnits(NumberAxis.createIntegerTickUnits());
        return chart;
    }

    @Override
    @Subscribe
    public void serialDataEventHandler(SerialDataEvent event) {
        if(event.getKey().equals(SERIAL_KEY)){
            series.add(System.currentTimeMillis(), event.getData());
        }
    }
}
```

AbstractModule has nothing to do with the eventBussing and extends JPanel. I am highly confused and don't see any reason as to why this doesn't work. If any one has any ideas I would really appreciate it, and if you need any more of the code I'm happy to provide it.

Thanks.

Edit: the last of the SingleSeriesLineChartModules to be created revives the event normally, the other 3 fail to revive it. It does not seem to matter if I register all but one of the instances or not, they still seem to be counted as registered i.e if I register module1, modules 2-4 act as if registered

Comment: Did the exception have a stack trace?

Comment: `@Override` and `@Subscribe` are both added to the method `serialDataEventHandler`. This means that `AbstractModule` defines that method. Can we see the complete definition of `serialDataEventHandler` in `AbstractModule`?

Comment: Also, which version of Guava are you using. Seeing the text message, it seems it's between 15 and 17 included. Can you reproduce the issue with 18?

Comment: AbstractModule is an abstract class implementing an interface which requires the serialDataEventHandler method, but doesn't actually define it, it just leaves that to any class which extends it.

Comment: I'm using guava 18-rc2 from maven

Comment: Is the method in the interface annotated with `@Subscribe` as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the issue. It appears that making the XYSeries static means that it is  then carried across all instances of the class, so when a new value is being added to the series for each instance, after it deals with the first one on the queue the others get the same series, when you try and add another data point with the same X value as an existing one (Which you aren't allowed to do), it throws an error, which runs all the way back up to the guava event. Not actually a guava issue in the end! All I have to do is make the XYSeries non-static

Sorry for wasting time!